# What does the word "enclosed" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I am not sure about the meaning of the word "enclosed" in the following made-up sentence:

> One of the great features of this tool is that it figures out where
>   the color should be, even if an area isn’t perfectly **enclosed**.

None of the words mentioned [in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enclosed) seems to fit here:

- 1 : closed in or fenced off
- 2 : included along with something else in a parcel or envelope

For context, the text is regarding a photo editing tool. It helps one use gradients more effectively.

Comment: I don't know why you think definition 1 isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

> One of the great features of this tool is that it figures out where the color should be, even if an area isn’t perfectly **enclosed**.

"Enclosed" in the above sentence is the past participle of the verb "enclose." It is not an adjective. You have looked at the wrong definition.
 Please check for "[enclose](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enclose)" in the dictionary, not "enclosed."

The right definition (please check the link) is  "to close in."